# Compile-time class inhertiance

Tags: c++, generics

Suppose you are given two classes `A` and `B` whose interface is not known in advance.  The goal is to generically 'combine' `A` and `B` into a new class called `AB` at *compile time*.

By combining I mean that all member functions and all member variables as well as all types of both `A` and `B` are present in `AB` with the same implementation.  Classical class inheritance does not suffice; I need to have it at compile time because run-time-dispatching is to costly in my application.  The naive solution would be to create an instance of each class and forward any call; this is not generic, however, because we assume the interface not to be fixed in advance.

Using concepts C++11 is fine if that helps.  A compiler error in case of a conflict in the interfaces of `A` and `B` is acceptable.

### Background

The classes implement utility functions that are based on some external data and are passed on as a template parameter.  There are several typical utilities that are often used and that I want to factor out (classes `A`, `B`, `C`), but not all are always applicable (if for example only `A` and `B` are applicable, then I want to use the utility `AB`).  The code is very low-level and the utility functions get called *very* often within a time-critical loop.

Comment: What would a class just inheriting from A and B miss ?

Comment: Um, inheritance is compile-time. So just derive your class from both `A` and `B`.

Comment: If `A` and `B` do not have virtual functions, then a class deriving from both does not use a virtual function table, i.e. it is "compile time". Is that what you need?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for the clarification! Especially to you Danvil. I always thought, inheritance would inherently involve run-time dispatching of members. So all I have to do is _not_ declaring any function in `A` or in `B` as `virtual`, right?! It turned out to be a stupid question, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-virtual functions no run-time overhead is incurred by inheritance.  So simply *do not* declare any of the members of `A` or `B` as `virtual` and no vtable will be created by the compiler.

A minimalistic example is

```
struct A { void f() { /* ... */ } };
struct B { void g() { /* ... */ } };

struct AB : public A, public B { };  // Provides both f and g.
```

N.b., if `A` and `B` overlap, the compiler will complain about ambiguities.

*(This answer is based on the comments and is given for completeness sake; credits are to the commentators.)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been addressed elsewhere already - what you're looking for is static inheritance. Two patterns implementing this are policy based design and curiously recurring templates. Beware of overloading issues.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  int a;
  A() : a(0) {}
  int foo_A() { return a; }
};

class B
{
public:
  int b;
  B() : b(1) {}
  int foo_B() { return b; }
};

template<class stinh1, class stinh2>
class AB : public stinh1, public stinh2
{

};


int main()
{
  AB<A,B> ab;
  cout << ab.foo_A() << endl << ab.foo_B() << endl;
  ab.a = 2;
  ab.b = 3;
  cout << ab.foo_A() << endl << ab.foo_B() << endl;
}
```

Comment: it achieves strict compile time inheritance. as a benefit, this allows you to have one declaration of AB, ad as many utility classes A, B..., honoring the same interface (methods/members) that you can 'plug' in as parameters, without changing AB

Comment: I don't see what the CRTP from your link has to do with your code. If I get it right, compile time dispatching is guaranteed simply by _not_ declaring `foo_A` and `foo_B` as `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is one way to go (probably the preferable one). You will have a small issue if A and B contain methods with the signature (same name and same parameters), this is hard to overcome without knowledge of the API before hand.
You could try to analyze the code statically, have a program read the code as text, parse the API and create a new text with both APIs combined, you will need to decide what to do with the same signature problem (do you call both? at what order? etc'). This solution is much, much harder and more prone to errors.